# Very high "hidden" memory usage inside a LXC container

Tags: memory, cgroups, container

We have a Proxmox VE (kernel 5.3) cluster running some IT services using LXC, one of which is used as a gateway for the whole intranet. It's set up with a Debian image and does forwarding & NAT using iptables. We're frequently seeing absurdly high memory usage in this container, and it just died (memory and swap both full).

`htop` reports full memory usage, but the processes listed (the RES column) sums up to less than 100 MiB:

[image: htop]

Host cgroup controller reports full usage for `memory.usage_in_bytes`:

```bsh
root@proxmox:/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/lxc/100# cat memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes
47140864
root@proxmox:/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/lxc/100# cat memory.usage_in_bytes
1066528768
```

Writing 3 into `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` on the host doesn't have any visible effect in the container.

Where is the "extra" memory? How to remediate this?

Comment: I am not sure how you are doing your memory calculations, just the `RES` amounts from the top `ruby` processes are consuming 580MB of RAM (57.2% of your total).  The `RES` column is represented in KiB by default.  I believe your issue is that you have allowed those `ruby` processes to allocate more virtual memory (`VIRT`) then you currently have available (1.3G vs 1G).  Check that there is not a memory leak in your `ruby` processes or run less `ruby` processes or get more RAM.

Comment: @GracefulRestart The top `ruby` items are **one single process** (htop shows threads as green and processes (main threads) as white). Also virtual memory isn't something important here.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.
Every cronjob that ran in my LXD container created a new transient user slice, like this one:

```
● session-c48037.scope - Session c48037 of user apache
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/session-c48037.scope; transient)
Transient: yes
   Active: active (abandoned) since Tue 2023-05-02 16:24:02 CEST; 13min ago
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 352.0K
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-48.slice/session-c48037.scope

May 02 16:24:02 pos34 systemd[1]: Started Session c48037 of user apache.
```

For reasons I don't understand yet, the sessions were never cleaned up after the cronjobs were done.
The kilobytes of memory added up over time and caused very high memory consumption by the kernel itself, reported as `SUnreclaim` in `/proc/meminfo`.
So while this doesn't answer "How to remediate this?", it might be the answer to "Where is the extra memory?".

This was observed on a Ubuntu 20.04 host system with a RockyLinux 8.7 LXD guest. LXD version 4.0.9 installed via Snap.